# Does every graph have a maximum stable set?

Tags: graph-theory, cardinals

(Don't confuse this question with [that one about maximal stable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906178/does-every-graph-have-a-maximal-stable-set).)

The answer is positive for finite graphs of course. In infinite graphs the matter becomes interesting. Let's revisit the definitions first.

> A (simple) graph is a pair $G=(V,E)$, with $V$ being the set of vertices and $E\subseteq\binom{V}{2}$ being a subset of the set of unordered pairs of $V$. For vertices $v,w\in V$ we write $vw:=\{v,w\}\in E$ and say $v$ and $w$ are adjacent.
>
> A subset $S$ of $V$ is called stable iff for any $v,w\in S$ we have $vw\notin E$, i.e. no two vertices of $S$ are adjacent. We call such a subset a stable set of $G$.
>
> A stable set $S$ of $G$ is called maximum iff for any stable set $T$ of $G$ we have $|T|\subseteq|S|$ ($|T|\leq|S|$ in finite case) where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of set $A$. If a maximum stable set of $G$ exists, we denote its cardinality by $\alpha(G)$.

In the finite case every graph has a maximum stable set because the biggest possible cardinality for the maximum stable set is $|V|$ (archieved if the finite graph is without edges) and then we can find a maximum stable set from $\{S:S\text{ is stable set}\}\subseteq 2^V$ because that set family is finite (from every finite set family we can find a set satisfying a property with that set having maximal cardinality).

I thought of an infinite **example** where this approach doesn't work anymore.

Let $G_0$ be the double ray, i.e. the countable 2-regular graph (you can get it from $\mathbb{Z}$ when you connect the numbers with difference $1$). Note that $|V(G_0)|=\alpha(G_0)=\aleph_0$. The double ray constitutes the first "row" of our final graph. We get $G_1$ from $G_0$ by adding $\aleph_1$ vertices to **each** of the vertices of $G_0$ (our first row), i.e. each of these clusters is connected only to a single vertex. Obviously, $|V(G_1)|=\alpha(G_1)=\aleph_1$. These $\aleph_0$ clusters of $\aleph_1$ vertices constitute our second row. We get $G_2$ from $G_1$ by adding $\aleph_2$ vertices to **each** vertex of the second row and have $|V(G_2)|=\alpha(G_2)=\aleph_2$. And so on.

This way we get a graph sequence $G_0,G_1,G_2,\ldots$ and can take their union $$G:=\textstyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}G_n := (\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}V(G_n), \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}E(G_n))$$
which constitutes a proper graph with cardinality $|V(G)|=\sup\{\aleph_n:n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$, which is, to my knowledge, a proper cardinal. Now I can see that $\alpha(G)=|V(G)|$ (probably), since I can take as a maximum stable set the vertices of each second row and $\sup\{\aleph_{2k}:k\in\mathbb{N}_0\}=\sup\{\aleph_n:n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$. But I still don't know how to prove this in general.

Hence the question: **Does every graph have a maximum stable set?** Please provide a proof or reference to one in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the vertex set
$$
V = \{(n, m) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \mid n \geq m\},
$$
and define an edge relation by
$$
E((n, m), (n', m')) \iff n \neq n'.
$$
Clearly, for each $k$, the set $\{(n, m) \in V \mid n = k\}$ is a stable set of cardinality $k + 1$. Furthermore, there can be no infinite stable set: if a node $(n, m)$ lies in the stable set, then all other nodes in the stable set must be of the form $(n, l)$, and there are only $n$ other such nodes. Thus the graph $(V, E)$ does not have a maximum stable set (in your sense).

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks!

Comment: @SK19 Plainly, "every graph has a maximum stable set" is equivalent to "every graph has a maximum clique". The obvious example of a graph with no maximum clique is the union of disjoint copies of $K_1,K_2,\dots,K_n,\dots.$ The complement of that graph is a graph with no maximum stable set, and that is the graph described in this answer.