# Does every graph have a maximal stable set?

Tags: graph-theory

(Don't confuse this question with [that one about maximum stable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906123/does-every-graph-have-a-maximum-stable-set).)

The answer is positive for finite graphs of course. In infinite graphs the matter becomes interesting. Let's revisit the definitions first.

> A (simple) graph is a pair $G=(V,E)$, with $V$ being the set of vertices and $E\subseteq\binom{V}{2}$ being a subset of the set of unordered pairs of $V$. For vertices $v,w\in V$ we write $vw:=\{v,w\}\in E$ and say $v$ and $w$ are adjacent.
>
> A subset $S$ of $V$ is called stable iff for any $v,w\in S$ we have $vw\notin E$, i.e. no two vertices of $S$ are adjacent. We call such a subset a stable set of $G$.
>
> A stable set $S$ of $G$ is called maximal iff for any $v\in V\setminus S$ holds that $S\cup\{v\}$ is no stable set of $G$ anymore.

In the finite case every graph has a maximal stable set because it has a maximum stable set and that implies a maximal stable set in the finite case.

In the infinite case that doesn't work anymore because there can be maximum sets which are not maximal (because adding a vertex to an infinite set doesn't change the cardinality).

However, the graphs I can think of always admit a maximal stable set. I tried to use the extensionality property of the rado graph to get another result, but that works only with finite subset, so once I've taken the union over a monotone series of stable sets I can't get any result. I've also tried working with $\mathbb{R}$ with $rs\in E$ iff (or iff not) $r-s\in\mathbb{Q}$, but I could find maximal sets again (take a representative system of the equivalence relation (or take $\mathbb{Q}$ in case of "iff not")). I'm at loss.

Hence the question: **Does every graph have a maximal stable set?** Please provide a proof or reference to one in your answer.

Comment: The assertion that every graph has a maximal stable set is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the axiom of choice, yes. If $X$ is the set of stable subsets of $(G,E)$, then we want to prove that $(X,\subseteq )$ has maximal elements. This is the case, because it is an inductive partial order. In fact, let $\mathscr C\subseteq X$ be a totally ordered subset. Then, $\bigcup\mathscr C$ (the union of the elements of $\mathscr C$) is an upper bound of $\mathscr C$ in $(X,\subseteq)$. In fact, we just need to prove that $\mathscr C$ is stable. Let $u,v\in \bigcup\mathscr C$. By definition, there are $U\in\mathscr C$ and $V\in\mathscr C$ such that $u\in U$ and $v\in V$. Since $(\mathscr C,\subseteq)$ is a total order, we do not lose generality by assuming that $U\subseteq V$, and therefore that $u\in V$ as well. Since by hypothesis $V$ is stable and $u,v\in V$, $uv\notin E$.

By Zorn's lemma, $X$ has maximal elements, QED.

*Added:* Viceversa, if every graph has a maximal stable set, let $X$ be a set and $\mathscr P$ be a partition of $X$. Let $G=X$ and define the adjacency relation $$uv\in E\iff (u\ne v\land \exists P\in\mathscr P, u\in P\land v\in P).$$

A maximal stable set of $(G,E)$ is precisely what the axiom of choice demands.